# How do I execute a Lisp program which has been stored in a variable?

Tags: function, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I have this code:

```
(setf prg '(+ 1 n)) ; define a very simple program
(print prg) ; print the program
```

I need to add more code so that when the above code is executed, it should set n to 1 and execute the
program stored in variable prg.

Comment: Prg is a list of 3 values, you need to evaluate it in an environment where n is bound to 0. You can bind n globally to 0 with defvar. Why not use a function instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do this:

```
(setf prg (lambda (n) + 1 n)) ; define a very simple program
(print (funcall prg 1))       ; print the program
```

In your example: `(+ 1 n)` is not a valid Common Lisp program.

EDIT: If you wanted to play with variables binding, you could also declare a variable:

```
(setf prg '(+ 1 n)) ; define a Common Lisp expression
(defparameter n 1)  ; bind a variable to the value 1
(print (eval prg))  ; evaluate the Common Lisp expression
> 2
```